# What location is this in this Season 7 Game of Thrones trailer?

Tags: game-of-thrones

A new official trailer was posted on the Game Of Thrones official Youtube channel today. You can view it here (obvious spoilers!):

Where is Dany in this video and

> what is the throne she seats herself in?

Could it be Pyke? Somewhere in Essos? Nowhere in particular and purely promotional material?

Comment: Voting to close per the future-works policy. https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5187/should-questions-about-future-works-be-closed-as-primarily-opinion-based?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: It's Dragonstone.

Comment: In the eyes of a white walker

Comment: Jon and Cersei are easy. Winterfell and Redkeep respectively. Dany's one is speculative. I think it is Dragonstone, given the geography.

Comment: annnnd I just noticed @BCdotWEB had also come to the same conclusion but about 11 hours before I saw this :D

Answer (score 3):

That is Dragonstone the traditional seat of the heir to the Iron Throne during the Targaryen Dynasty.

During the show it has been the seat of Stannis Baratheon as given to him by his brother King Robert Baratheon. It was then empty until Season 7 when Daenerys returns to it.

This is Castle Dragonstone on Dragonstone island, note you can see Dany's dragons in this image:

[image: Dragonstone castle]

And this is the throne made out of Dragonglass, what the maesters call obsidian, you can clearly see Dany sat on the throne with her Dothraki blood riders gaurding her:

[image: Dragonstone throne]

Note the Game of Thrones Season 7 Episode 1 is also called "Dragonstone" and shows Dany arriving there. There are also many other quotes throughout the show but this one seems the clearest:

> Tell Jon Snow that his queen invites him to come to **Dragonstone** and bend the knee.
>   <sub>Game of Thrones, S07 E02, "Stormborn"</sub>